# Alternative for overchallenged

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm a non-native speaker, looking for a single term to describe the quality of feeling overwhelmed with a task of work in a person.

I found **overchallenged** on dict.cc, but when I wanted to look it up on oxforddictionaries.com or merriam-webster, I found no match. Thus, I conclude the term is not commonly used amongst native speakers.

What alternatives are there?

> He felt [overchallenged] by having to carry all the bags by himself.

Comment: Overwhelmed is more natural for that sentence.

Comment: @TheNate Please post answers as answers, not comments!

Comment: I like "overwhelmed" but it seems more like word used at the end of an accumulation of problems that finally swamp ones abilities.  Here he has "bags"; no history to it.  While you can get "overwhelmed" with a heavy bag, it seems too big a word to use.  The author's "task" may have many steps that can eventually "overwhelm". I can't think of anything better thou.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Burdened** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/burdened)

> to load or overload;
> *"she walked forwards burdened with a wooden box"*
>
> cause (someone) worry, hardship, or distress.
> *"they were not yet burdened with adult responsibility"*

<sub>Other suggestions: [encumbered](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encumber), [overloaded](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overload), [hampered](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hamper), [weigh down](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/weigh+down)</sub>

Comment: Along the same lines: "Overburdened" is a word.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the word *overtaxed*.

> **Overtaxed** *verb*
>   2 Make excessive demands on (a person’s strength, abilities, etc.): *do athletes overtax their hearts?*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/overtax?q=overtaxed)

Answer (score 7):

Consider **swamped**, already mentioned in @Andy_Fielding answer.

> Definition: to be plunged into or overwhelmed with something,
>   especially something that keeps one busy, worried, etc.
>
> Example: *I’m sorry I didn’t respond to your email. I’m really swamped with work right now*.

Also **overstrectched**.

> "overstrecht" definition : to make excessive demands or put excessive
>   pressure on (oneself, finances, etc); overburden.

Answer (score 5):

Those suggestions are good when you're referring to a single task.

When you're referring to multiple tasks, a good word is *swamped*:

"I can't handle more work this week—I'm already swamped!"

It creates an image of sinking into a swamp, being overwhelmed by water (and maybe crocodiles!).

Answer (score 5):

Consider **deluged**.

> Definition: a large amount of things that come at the same time
>
> Example: *he has been deluged with offers of work*.

Answer (score 3):

***[Overworked](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overwork)*** is a good candidate

> *(transitive verb)* to cause to work too hard, too long, or to exhaustion {*overworked* the horses}

[Merriam-Webster]

**Usage:**

> He felt ***overworked*** by having to carry all the bags by himself.

Answer (score 3):

Consider, ***plowed under***

> plow under
>
> To overwhelm, as with burdens: *was plowed under with work*. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plow+under)
>
> To overwhelm someone or something: *My teachers have plowed me under with work this week*. *We were plowed under with dirty laundry*. [American Heritage Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/plow+under)
>
> To cause to disappear: bury, overwhelm [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plow%20under)
>
> *He felt plowed under by having to carry all the bags by himself.*

Also, ***bogged down***

> bog down
>
> 1. get stuck while doing something
> 2. cause to get stuck as if in a mire [MnemonicDictionary](http://www.mnemonicdictionary.com/word/bog%20down)

Answer (score 0):

**encumbered**

1. To cause to have difficulty in moving or in accomplishing something; burden: "a hiker encumbered with a heavy pack; a student encumbered with responsibilities."
2. To hinder or impede the action or performance of: "restrictions that encumber police work."